# returned force close when using send sms from a class

Tags: android, class

i want to run Send sms in another calss but when i start the virtual device its returned me "unfortunatly ... has stop".

this is SensSms

```
public class SendSmsClass extends Activity {

    public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber,String message) {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();


         String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
            int messageCount = parts.size();

            Log.i("Message Count", "Message Count: " + messageCount);

            ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

            for (int j = 0; j < messageCount; j++) {
                sentIntents.add(sentPI);
                deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
            }

            // ---when the SMS has been sent---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "دستور ارسال شد ، منتظر دریافت پاسخ باشید",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "عدم وجود سیگنال",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "خطای نامشخص",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode()) {

                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "دستور به دستگاه رسید",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "دستور به دستگاه نرسید",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
           /* sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents); */
    }
```

}

and i called this class from another activity to send sms in this code:

```
    public class AdminNumber extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_number);

    SendSmsClass ssc = new SendSmsClass();
    ssc.sendSMS("3432", "test");
```

this is my logcat:

```
 06-23 04:47:56.945: W/dalvikvm(1093): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught        exception (group=0xb2aedba8)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): Process: com.example.gpsportalsms, PID: 1093
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity        ComponentInfo{com.example.gpsportalsms/com.example.gpsportalsms.AdminNumber}:      java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:478)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:467)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.example.gpsportalsms.SendSmsClass.sendSMS(SendSmsClass.java:33)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.example.gpsportalsms.AdminNumber.onCreate(AdminNumber.java:27)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-23 04:47:56.965: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     ... 11 more
```

But  When I use my code in one class file, it runs perfectly
whats my mistake?

Comment: please post logcat exception?

Comment: Please post the output from logcat

Comment: why your extending SendSmsClass from Activity???

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> have you defined this in your manifest??

Comment: yes. i used permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS in maniefest.

Comment: The `SendSmsClass` should not extend `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove extends Activity from SendSms class and it surely worked.. try now

And also you need Context for sendsms then you can pass in it constructor from AdminNumber Activity ,

See Modified code for you

```
public class SendSmsClass {
Context c;
SendSmsClass(Context c){
       this.c=c;
 }
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber,String message) {

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();


     String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
        int messageCount = parts.size();

        Log.i("Message Count", "Message Count: " + messageCount);

        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        for (int j = 0; j < messageCount; j++) {
            sentIntents.add(sentPI);
            deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
        }

        // ---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                    Toast.makeText(c, "دستور ارسال شد ، منتظر دریافت پاسخ باشید",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(c, "عدم وجود سیگنال",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(c, "خطای نامشخص",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
        c.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {

                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(c, "دستور به دستگاه رسید",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(c, "دستور به دستگاه نرسید",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
           /* sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents); */
    }

and in AdminNumber:

```
 SendSmsClass ssc = new SendSmsClass(AdminNumber.this);
ssc.sendSMS("3432", "test");
```

Use **c** anywhere if you need context...

Good luck

Comment: this code returned some error on class example:
can,t find registerReceiver method; and when i change registerReceiver to c.registerReceiver im have problem with  SendSmsClass ssc = new SendSmsClass(AdminNumber.this); "this" is returned error i had to remove the "this" but when i run the app it was returned "unfortunatly ... has stop";

Comment: write getApplicationContext() into SendSmsClass ssc = new SendSmsClass(getApplicationContext()); and run...what happenes??

Comment: it was returned The "constructor SendSmsClass(Context) is undefined"